# Is Parse LiveQuery available for use in Android development?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I saw that Parse had introduced live querying into Javascript and iOS, but I have not heard anything about Android.  Is it available?

Comment: a minimal effort of searching will give you the answer is about 2 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Parse Live Query support for Android is available here now: 
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseLiveQuery-Android

Answer (score 0):

It is not available officially yet but you can follow this [issue #437](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/437)

Answer (score 0):

It is available [here](https://github.com/TGIO/ParseLiveQuery) by TGIO. I haven't tried it yet but I think it works.